# Template Toolkit - Display array by ID

Tags: json, perl, template-toolkit

I want to display a block of an array by the ID - can I do this using Template Toolkit or will it be in the Perl controller side? (I'm using Dancer & REST::Client to grab the JSON)

This is the JSON:

```
    {
        "user":
        [
            { 
            "id": 12345,
                "name": bob,
                "age": 22,
                "birth_place": "London"
            },
            { 
            "id": 12346,
                "name": amy,
                "age": 20,
                "birth_place": "London"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm getting the ID of the user in the controller so I can display the ID in the template with `[% user.id %]`. So I want to be able to basically do

1) If user id matches the id of one of the id's in the JSON

2) Display data from that block

```
Name: [% content.name %]
Age: [% content.age %]
Birth Place: [% content.birth_place %]
```

Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check for multiple users, you really want a hash rather than an array.

```
my $data = decode_json(...);
my %data_by_userid = map { $_->{id} => $_ } @{ $data->{user} };
```

Template parameters:

```
data_by_userid => \%data_by_userid
```

Then, you'd use

```
[% user = data_by_userid.$id -%]
[% IF user -%]
Name: [% user.name %]
Age: [% user.age %]
Birth Place: [% user.birth_place %]
[% END -%]
```

---

If you only need one user in the template, just use

```
my $data = decode_json(...);
my ($user) = grep { $_->{id} == $id } @{ $data->{user} };
```

Template parameters:

```
user => $user
```

Then, you'd use

```
[% IF user -%]
Name: [% user.name %]
Age: [% user.age %]
Birth Place: [% user.birth_place %]
[% END -%]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you a full solution, because it's long, complicated and you don't give nearly enough detail to allow it to be possible in the first place.

However, you can decode JSON like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON; 

my $JSON_text = '{
        "user":
        [
            { 
            "id": 12345,
                "name": "bob",
                "age": "22",
                "birth_place": "London"
            },
            { 
            "id": 12346,
                "name": "amy",
                "age": "20",
                "birth_place": "London"
            }
        ]
    }';

my $JSON = decode_json ( $JSON_text ); 
foreach my $element ( @{$JSON->{"user"}} ) {
   print $element->{"id"}, "\n";
}
```

I'll leave it to you to try and figure out how to extract the fields you desire into your template. By the way - the JSON you posted isn't valid, so I've had to amend it slightly.  Hopefully that's a transposition error on your source.